# Sub-sub-Treeview (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am attempting to make a treeview out of a list of requirements - the requirements are in a list and go like "1.2.1.a_1" and "1.2.2.b_2". The code below currently makes a nice treeview that creates "Requirement 1" as a primary node, and nice "1.x" as subnodes with all of the requirements nicely listed under that "1.x" bit. My problem is that I want to go deeper - make expandable nodes for all "1.x.x" items (where both Xs are numbers) - so "1.2.3.a_1" and "1.2.3.b_1" are under the same parent node or "1.2.3". Not all requirements have a number for the 3rd non-period character (i.e. 2.1.a_1 might exist). I am just at a loss on how to make this happen... Please help.

```
private void LoadtheNarrativeTreeView() // load up the treeview on the narrative page
{
    Narrative_one_Treeview.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        TreeViewItem rootnode = new TreeViewItem();
        rootnode.Header = "Requirement " + i.ToString();

        //TreeNode rootnode = new TreeNode("Requirement " + i.ToString(), 9, 9);
        Narrative_one_Treeview.Items.Add(rootnode);
        for (int s = 1; s <= 12; s++)
        {
            bool testsub = (theROC.FieldVariablesList.Exists(x => x.name.StartsWith(i.ToString() + "." + s.ToString())));
            if (testsub == false)
            { break; }

            List<FieldVariable> clist = new List<FieldVariable>(theROC.FieldVariablesList.Where(x => x.name.StartsWith(i.ToString() + "." + s.ToString())));
            FieldVariable firstsub = new FieldVariable(theROC.FieldVariablesList.First(x => x.name.StartsWith(i.ToString() + "." + s.ToString()))); // 1.1, 1.2
            TreeViewItem subrootnode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = i.ToString() + "." + s.ToString()};
            rootnode.Items.Add(subrootnode);
            foreach (FieldVariable FV in clist.ToList())
            {
                TreeViewItem cnode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = FV.name };

                subrootnode.Items.Add(cnode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ever know `HierarchicalDataTemplate`?

Comment: Instead of passing a Linq query to `new List<T>()` why not just use `ToList()` at the end instead?